# Buffered image is null

Tags: java, python, numpy

I am trying to send frames to java app from python app. Firstly I create a blank image on python side with numpy array and then wanna send it to java app and display it on the java side. But the bufferedimage on java side is null here is python code;

```
import socket
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import base64
import json
from lib2to3.pytree import Leaf
from lib2to3.fixer_util import String

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 5555
try:
    socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
except:
    print "We cannot find the server !!!!"
    print "Terminating the program . . ."
    #exit(0)

img = np.zeros((300, 300, 3), np.uint8) 
obj = NumpyEncoder()   
outjson = {}
outjson['img'] = base64.b64encode(img)
outjson['leaf'] = "leaf"
json_data = json.dumps(outjson)
socket.sendall(json_data

socket.close()
```

and here is java side;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageFormatDescription;
import com.sun.prism.Image;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class ServerFrame extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
public static BufferedImage bufferedImage;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws JSONException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerFrame frame = new ServerFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;


    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Server Socket Has Been Started . . .");
    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("User Connected :" + clientSocket.getLocalAddress().toString());

    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    if(in == null) System.exit(1);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           sb.append(line);
        }
    //System.out.println(sb.toString());

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
    String leaf_name = json.getString("leaf");
    String mat_string = json.getString("img");
    byte[] raw_data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(mat_string);
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(raw_data));
    if(bufferedImage == null) System.out.println("warning");
    System.out.println(raw_data.length);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("image.jpg");
    try {
        fos.write(raw_data);
    }
    finally {
        fos.close();
    }
    /*JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(50,50);
    panel.setSize(dim);
    panel.setMinimumSize(dim);
    panel.setMaximumSize(dim);
    panel.setPreferredSize(dim);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("hello");
    label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());
    panel.add(label);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bufferedImage)));*/
    br.close();
    clientSocket.close();
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public ServerFrame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
}

}
```

Can you see the problem, Why is it null ?

Comment: read returns null when no `ImageReader` is able to decode the stream. I suspect that the format isn't compatible with standard java libraries

Comment: A *numpy array* **is not** a binary image that `ImageReader` can read. **Base64** encoding a *numpy array* does not make it an image.

Comment: And can you suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The Base64 property in the database was null. To fix this issue, open the database manually or otherwise insert a base64 value(s) to the property causing the null return. I had the same issue initializing this:
WebImage image = new WebImage(i.ImageData);

The ImageData, highlighted was null, hence the error. Solution was to insert a Base64 value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPQtb.png)

Comment: Please do not add data as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121). Instead, add the data in a codeblock or table. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change to :

```
outjson['img'] = base64.b64encode(img.tobytes())
```